# Getting Data from WinForms ListView Control

Tags: vb.net, winforms, listview

I need to retrieve my data from a ListView control set up in Details mode with 5 columns.

I tried using this code:

```
MessageBox.Show(ManageList.SelectedItems(0).Text)
```

And it works, but only for the first selected item (item 0). If I try this:

```
MessageBox.Show(ManageList.SelectedItems(2).Text)
```

I get this error:

> InvalidArgument=Value of '2' is not valid for 'index'. Parameter name: index

I have no clue how I can fix this, any help?

Edit: Sorry, should have said, I'm using Windows.Forms :)

Comment: SelectedItems is a collection-- to ensure you *always* get the right number to operate on you could use a FOR EACH in the collection; anytime you hard code an index you're asking for trouble ;<>)

Answer (score 0):

Right, from what I've tested:

```
Private Sub Button1Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    For index As Integer = 0 To Me.listView1.SelectedItems.Count - 1
        MessageBox.Show(Me.listView1.SelectedItems(index).Text)
    Next
End Sub
```

(items added like this:)

```
For i As Integer = 0 To 99
    Me.listView1.Items.Add(String.Format("test{0}", i))
Next
```

It  just works.

So are you sure you have selected more than 1 item? 
Could you please show us more code? :)

Comment: Hi, I'm using VB.NET, not C#. But I'll try and some how port it over or something. Thanks for the reply :)